# Preserve formatting on Configuration.Save()

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationsection, system.configuration, xml-formatting

I have custom `ConfigurationSection` and call `Configuration.Save()` after some modifications against it:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = "My.config" },
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
if (config != null)
{
    // do stuff

    config.Save();
}
```

Currently it performs some formatting of resulting XML. For example, replaces tabs with spaces, inserts line-breaks if it thinks that it's too long (> ~130 characters), etc.

How can I preserve or control that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save function internally uses the `XmlUtilWriter` class which is also an internal class under `System.Configuration` namespace. Your best change is to either try to modify the class with reflection at runtime, or go the easy way and do a serialization manually.

Comment: I wish I had a possibility to override the behavior. Very strange that nothing is done yet in the direction